# Send Email After Three Files Uploaded

Tags: sharepoint-designer, visual-studio

We're still stuck on SharePoint Server 2010; will hopefully migrate to 2016 in the near future. I could really use some help with this task because I feel like I've spent countless hours, and haven't gotten anywhere.

Task is simple: send an email to specified users after a user uploads three files that end with "_XYZ", "_ABC", "_DEF" to a designated folder inside a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a SharePoint Designer workflow solution...

- Create a list in the same site named something like "download count".
- Add three columns: user, filetype (if you are uniquely tracking file types) and count.
- Create a workflow for the library that:

  - fires on each new item (an upload)
  - checks for the pattern (_ABC) in the file name
  - finds or adds an item to "download count" and updates the count
  - if the count is greater than 2, sends an email.

Comment: Thank you @mike I have a list now that gets updated. However, when I add an item to the folder, three separate list items (in download count) get created with name = name of the filename. How can I get the name in new list (download count) to be folder name? These three files will be uploaded inside a folder. And there can be many folders, all will have these three files.

Comment: I DID IT! path is the key. I did it! Forever indebted to you!

Comment: Cool! Glad to help! (Write a how-to blog article somewhere and share your success!)